# Function in function will not be called multiple times if requested?

Tags: shell, pipe, function

```
> cat b.txt 
function first
    {
    sleep 1
    echo $(echo $$)
    }

function second
    {
    openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k "$(first)"
    }

echo nyi | second | second | second
> 
> time sh -x b.txt 
+ echo nyi
+ second
+ second
+ second
++ first
++ sleep 1
++ first
++ sleep 1
++ first
++ sleep 1
+++ echo 32383
+++ echo 32383
++ echo 32383
++ echo 32383
+ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k 32383
+++ echo 32383
+ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k 32383
++ echo 32383
+ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k 32383
ɚ��2;��<�Vp��H�����F�q�AHO��Sܽd��d4��X��#}
real    0m1.026s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.025s
>
```

**Question**: why doesn this script runs for at least 3 seconds?

There is a "sleep 1" in the first function and it should be called 3 times in the second function.

According to the "real    0m1.026s" it seems that the sleep is only executed once. Or if it is parallel (??) then how can I make it linear?

Comment: As I can see `first` is called **3** times, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts of a pipeline are started (close to) simultaneously.

All three invocations of `second` will start at the same time. The three subshells that this gives rise to will invoke `first` to expand `"$(first)"` and the three `sleep 1` calls will happen concurrently (you can see in the trace output that they *do* happen).

It's only the I/O that serializes a pipeline, i.e. one process in the pipeline waiting for input from the previous, or waiting to have its output read by the next.

To have the bits of the pipeline start, run and exit in sequence:

```
echo nyi | second >out1
second <out1 >out2
second <out2
```

That is, run them separatedly and store the intermediate results in files.

Comment: wow, Thanks!, but how can I make it linear instead of concurrent? I don't understand how could it be concurrent if it is a pipe that should listen to the input and when it gets the input it can run, strange

Comment: @pepite But the point is, it doesn't listen for input when the shell is running the `first` function. In fact, at that point, the associated `openssl` command hasn't even been started yet.

Comment: @pepite: A UNIX (or, for that matter, also Windows) pipeline works by starting up both ends concurrently and connecting the output of the left-hand end to the input of the right-hand end. If you write `program1 | program2 | program3` all the three programs start concurrently and work in parallel, with `program2` reading its input from the output of `program1` (and of course waiting if necessary for `program1` to produce some output) and `program3` reading its input from the output of `program2` (and of course waiting if necessary for `program2` to produce some output).

Comment: any other solution to avoid disk write? Thanks!

Comment: @pepite You could try something like `echo nyi | { sleep 1; second } | { sleep 2; second } | { sleep 3; second }`.